# PL/SQL hint - When to use use_nl versus use_hash?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a very naive question;

I am currently quite unsure how the performance gains will be different for these two hints. Generally, when do I want to use nested loop over hash, and vise versa?

Comment: don´t use hint. Unless you are in a very very specific situation where after optimizing your query the CBO is still inadequate. In 95% of the time the problem is the query, not the cbo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, nested loop joins work best when there are useful indexes and the percentage of data returned is small.  Hash joins work best when there are no useful indexes or when the join will return a large percentage of rows.

It is usually better to avoid hints and let Oracle decide how to build an execution plan.